# xml how to parse in php

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I have this xml

http://www.scorespro.com/rss/live-soccer.xml

the structure is this :

```
 <rss>
 <channel>
 <item>
 <title>
 </title>
 </item>
 </channel>
 </rss>
```

I want to get the information about the titles, so i'm trying to do this, but without success.

```
  $xml = simplexml_load_file('http://www.scorespro.com/rss/live-soccer.xml');
foreach($xml->item as $item)
 {
 echo $item->title;
 }
```

I already did  print_r($xml) to see if is parsing correctly the url that i'm giving.

Comment: Your `$xml` holds the rss, not the channel ;) so `foreach($xml->channel->item ....`

Comment: Thanks, it was simply as that. Really thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$xml` has root node, in this case `<rss>`:

```
foreach($xml->channel->item as $item)
```

You can also use [XPath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) to get the items:

```
$items = $result = $xml->xpath('/rss/channel/item');
```